# Mi aplicacion va muy lenta en el dispositivo físico

Tags: android, android-studio

tengo el siguiente código en java de una activity y no sé porqué en el dispositivo físico va muy lenta la app:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.FirebaseAppIndex;

import es.aandg.demo.Incidencias.MapaIncidencias;
import es.aandg.demo.R;
import es.aandg.demo.Utils.SaveImage;

public class DetalleIncidenciasAdmin extends AppCompatActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback, View.OnClickListener {

Toolbar toolbar;
CollapsingToolbarLayout collapser;

//Acciones
ImageView borrar;
ImageView archivar;
ImageView enviar;

TextView nUsuario;
TextView fecha;
TextView descripcion;
TextView direccion;

LinearLayout linear1;
LinearLayout linear2;
LinearLayout linear3;
ImageView img1;
ImageView img2;
ImageView img3;

ImageView imgPrincipal;

MapFragment mapa;

static IncidenciaItem incidencia;

public static void newIntent(Context c, @Nullable IncidenciaItem m){

    incidencia=m;

    Intent i=new Intent(c, MapaIncidencias.class);
    c.startActivity(i);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle_incidencias_admin);

    instancias();
    confToolbar();
    setearTextos();
    setearImagenes();
    acciones();

    mapa.getMapAsync(this);


}

private void instancias() {
    incidencia=new IncidenciaItem("Mi gato s eha caido a un pozo", "23/05/2017 15:01", "Adrian garrido", "kjga jkhgakjahg kajhy akjha kjah kj a" +
            "k jah akj hakj akjah ka ajh akjha kajh akjah kjah akj hakjha kjah akjh akj hakjha " +
            "lkajhalkjal kaj", null, null, null, "C/ puerto, 2 mnijares avila 05461 españa", "40.296706", "-4.838145");
    toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_detalleIncidenciasAdmin);
    collapser= (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapser_detalleIncidenciasAdmin);

    borrar= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_borrar_detalleIncidenciaAdmin);
    archivar= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_archivar_detalleIncidenciaAdmin);
    enviar= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_enviar_detalleIncidenciaAdmin);

    nUsuario= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_nUsuario_detalleIncidenciasAdmin);
    fecha= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_fecha_detalleIncidenciaAdmin);
    descripcion= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_detalle_detalleIncidenciaAdmin);
    direccion= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_direccion_detalleIncidenciasAdmin);

    linear1= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_1_detalleIncidenciasAdmin);
    linear2= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_2_detalleIncidenciasAdmin);
    linear3= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_3_detalleIncidenciasAdmin);
    img1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_foto1_detalleIncidenciasAdmin);
    img2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_foto2_detalleIncidenciasAdmin);
    img3= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_foto3_detalleIncidenciasAdmin);

    mapa= (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapa_statico_detalleIncidenciasAdmin);

    imgPrincipal= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_principal_detalleIncidenciasAdmin);


}

private void confToolbar() {

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if(getSupportActionBar() !=null) //habilitar el up button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

   getSupportActionBar().setTitle(incidencia.getNombre());

}


private void setearTextos() {

    nUsuario.setText(incidencia.getNombreUsuario());
    fecha.setText(incidencia.getFecha());
    descripcion.setText(incidencia.getDetalle());
    direccion.setText(incidencia.getDireccion());
}


private void setearImagenes() {

    //Setear imagen principal ir bajando desde la 3 hasta la 1 para ber que imagenes hay, ya que la 1 es mas importante
    if(incidencia.getImg3()!=null){
        linear3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //imgPrincipal.setImageBitmap();
    }else {
        linear3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if(incidencia.getImg2()!=null){
        linear2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }else {
        linear2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if(incidencia.getImg1()==null){
        linear1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.mijares_cascada);
        imgPrincipal.setImageResource(R.drawable.mijares_cascada);

    }else{
        linear1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    //Dependiendo de como vaya a tratar las imagenes, si desde una url o desde bits se verá como se hace

}

private void acciones() {

    borrar.setOnClickListener(this);
    archivar.setOnClickListener(this);
    enviar.setOnClickListener(this);
    img1.setOnClickListener(this);
    img2.setOnClickListener(this);
    img3.setOnClickListener(this);

}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Float.valueOf(incidencia.getLat()),Float.valueOf(incidencia.getLon()))));
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(Float.valueOf(incidencia.getLat()),Float.valueOf(incidencia.getLon())), 18);
    googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
    googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.estilo_mapa));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.img_borrar_detalleIncidenciaAdmin:
            confirmarBorrado();
            break;
        case R.id.img_archivar_detalleIncidenciaAdmin:
            archivarIncidencia();
            break;
        case R.id.img_enviar_detalleIncidenciaAdmin:
            break;
        case R.id.img_foto1_detalleIncidenciasAdmin:
            generarDialogo(view.getId()).show();
            break;
        case R.id.img_foto2_detalleIncidenciasAdmin:
            break;
        case R.id.img_foto3_detalleIncidenciasAdmin:
            break;
    }
}

private AlertDialog generarDialogo(int id) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final Context c=this;
    View v;
    v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogo_foto_incidencia,null);
    builder.setView(v);
    final ImageView imagen_principal= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_principal_dialogoFotoIncidencia);
    ImageView descargar= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_descargar_dialogoFotoIncidencia);
    switch (id){
        case R.id.img_foto1_detalleIncidenciasAdmin:
            //imagen=incidencia.getImg1();
            imagen_principal.setImageResource(R.drawable.mijares_cascada);
            break;
        case R.id.img_foto2_detalleIncidenciasAdmin:
            break;
        case R.id.img_foto3_detalleIncidenciasAdmin:
            break;
    }

    descargar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //convertir imagen
            imagen_principal.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap bmp=imagen_principal.getDrawingCache();

            //guardar imagen
            SaveImage guardar=new SaveImage();
            guardar.SaveImage(c,bmp);

        }
    });

    return  builder.create();
}

private void archivarIncidencia() {

    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),getString(R.string.incidenciaGuardada), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction(getString(R.string.deshacer), new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //deshacer el guardado por detras(asincrono)
                }
            }).show();


}

private void confirmarBorrado() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.atencion)
            .setMessage(R.string.infoBorraIncidenciaAdmin)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.aceptar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    //borrar en base de datos con clase asincrona
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });


    builder.create().show();



}
}
```

A continuación os dejo lo que me deja el logcat en la salida:

```
    08-29 09:58:34.615 1627-2166/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
    08-29 09:58:34.624 1627-1640/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
    08-29 09:58:34.633 1627-2119/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
    08-29 09:58:34.641 1627-1640/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
    08-29 09:58:34.648 1627-2119/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
    08-29 09:58:34.657 1627-1640/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
    08-29 09:58:34.664 1627-2119/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
    08-29 09:58:34.680 1928-2828/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout:
    08-29 09:58:34.681 1928-2828/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    08-29 09:58:34.681 1928-2828/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:    wrp.a(:com.google.android.gms:58)
    08-29 09:58:34.811 1928-2828/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout:
    08-29 09:58:34.811 1928-2828/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    08-29 09:58:34.811 1928-2828/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:    wrp.a(:com.google.android.gms:58)
    08-29 09:58:35.053 1928-2828/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/GLSUser: [AppCertManager] IOException while requesting key: 
                                                                              java.io.IOException: Invalid device key response.
                                                                                  at etg.a(:com.google.android.gms:10)
                                                                                  at etg.a(:com.google.android.gms:69)
                                                                                  at ete.a(:com.google.android.gms:11)
                                                                                  at eta.a(:com.google.android.gms:0)
                                                                                  at esz.a(:com.google.android.gms:9)
                                                                                  at com.google.android.gms.auth.account.be.legacy.AuthCronChimeraService.b(:com.google.android.gms:8)
                                                                                  at eca.call(:com.google.android.gms:2)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                  at lhb.run(:com.google.android.gms:24)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                  at lmc.run(:com.google.android.gms:0)
                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    08-29 09:58:35.153 1627-2013/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
    08-29 09:59:00.071 1224-1290/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 8 syncs in 60s
    08-29 09:59:26.567 1627-1645/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
    08-29 09:59:26.567 1627-1645/system_process E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq
                                                                        java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                                            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
                                                                            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
                                                                            at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.KernelCpuSpeedReader.readDelta(KernelCpuSpeedReader.java:49)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8002)
                                                                            at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366)
                                                                            at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                                            at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
                                                                         Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                                            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                                            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                                            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
                                                                            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103) 
                                                                            at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.KernelCpuSpeedReader.readDelta(KernelCpuSpeedReader.java:49) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8002) 
                                                                            at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366) 
                                                                            at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
                                                                            at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46) 
    08-29 09:59:26.568 1627-1645/system_process E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime
                                                                          java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                              at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                                              at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
                                                                              at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
                                                                              at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.KernelUidCpuTimeReader.readDelta(KernelUidCpuTimeReader.java:71)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8031)
                                                                              at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366)
                                                                              at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                                              at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
                                                                           Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                                              at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                                              at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                                              at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                                              at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
                                                                              at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103) 
                                                                              at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.KernelUidCpuTimeReader.readDelta(KernelUidCpuTimeReader.java:71) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8031) 
                                                                              at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366) 
                                                                              at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
                                                                              at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46) 
    08-29 09:59:35.226 2476-18963/com.google.android.gms W/art: No such thread id for suspend: 53
    08-29 10:00:00.017 1627-1643/system_process I/ProcessStatsService: Prepared write state in 1ms
    08-29 10:00:00.018 1627-1643/system_process I/ProcessStatsService: Prepared write state in 1ms
    08-29 10:00:00.040 1627-1642/system_process I/ProcessStatsService: Pruning old procstats: /data/system/procstats/state-2017-08-15-01-06-00.bin
    08-29 10:00:00.072 1224-1290/? D/hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 6 syncs in 60s
    08-29 10:00:21.503 1627-1780/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
    08-29 10:00:21.508 2476-18975/com.google.android.gms I/EventLogChimeraService: Aggregate from 1503999038180 (log), 1503999016440 (data)
    08-29 10:00:21.558 1627-2013/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
    08-29 10:00:21.564 1627-2166/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
    08-29 10:00:21.565 1627-1780/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
    08-29 10:00:21.568 2476-18979/com.google.android.gms W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/x86_64
    08-29 10:00:21.943 1627-2119/system_process I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
```

Creo que puede ser por lo del `hw_composer` pero no sé lo que es.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Adrian, esta pregunta es **muy amplia** y posiblemente no reproducible. Has de investigar metodos que puedan aligerar la carga de datos como fotos, usar menos resolucion o otras codificaciones. Un saludo

Comment: También puede influir el hardware del dispositivo físico, frente al que hayas utilizado en el emulador.

Comment: El movil  es bastante potente, además sólo es una activity con muy pocos componentes y una sola imagen que no tiene casi resolución, de ahí mi problema

Comment: Otro problema puede ser la carga de imagenes, si tienes imagenes muy pesadas que quieres cargar visualmente mediante el layout o con codigo. Intenta usar metodos asyncronos o librerias como Glide o Picasso. Porque si intentas cargarlas todas en el hilo de la interfaz, te va a ir muy lenta.